# spring-boot embedded kafka issue : I am getting Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)

Tags: integration-testing, embedded-kafka

1. I am writing integration test cases using spring boot, embedded kafka, and temporal. I am trying to send a message on a kafka topic.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext
@EmbeddedKafka(
        partitions = 5,
        controlledShutdown = true,
        brokerProperties = {
                "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092",
                "port=9092"
        })
public class OutboundFlowIT {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OutboundFlowIT.class);

    private TestWorkflowEnvironment testEnv;

    private Worker worker;

    private WorkflowClient workflowClient;

    @Autowired
    private ActivityService activityService;

    @Autowired
    private EventSender sender;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
         // some setup code.
    }

    @Test
    public void processOutboundFinancialMessage_shouldTriggerAllSteps_WhenOK() throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        // logic for sending message to intended topic.
    }
```

2. But I am getting below error.

```
org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 369296129 larger than 104857600)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:105) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:447) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:397) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:678) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:580) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:485) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:861) ~[kafka_2.12-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:760) ~[kafka_2.12-2.5.1.jar:na]
```

3. I have also added the below configurations in kafka.properties but I am getting the same issue as above.

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.max.request.size=569296129
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.max.partition.fetch.bytes=369296129
```

I am new to kafka , please help me.

Answer (score 0):

How do you send the messages to the kafka broker? You should use the kafka protocol and not using  HTTP request, resemble issues states this is the error comes from